# Explaining to the user that the mobile version of a product is not available

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, mobile-web

We have this product that we still are developing and we haven't created the mobile version for it. Users currently are accessing the product via mobiles too.

How can I let them know that we haven't created a mobile version yet? How should I approach this?

Comment: Does the product work on mobile browsers? That one is much more important than having a "mobile" version. Keep in mind, while a mobile version sometimes looks pretty, users do appreciate a version that actually works and offers the full functionality.

Comment: Of course you can open it on the browsers through your mobile, but I was thinking something like adding a message or something like we are going to develop the app for mobile too but that is going to take a while soo, what do you think I should do?

Comment: I'm slightly surprised you didn't use [mobile first](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/mobile-first-indexing.html) design. Are your users an unusual or special demographic with uncommon UI priorities?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Hi, yeah me too I wasn't a part of the team when the product was built and I can't make that decision, I don't know how the founders thought this through but there must have been a reason. I cannot go deeper into details concerning the product but I agree with you.

Comment: There usually is no reason. Just bad product management. Happens a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have 4 approaches: a blocking/obstructing notice, something that takes a place of an ad, a tiny link, or nothing.

- Adding an obstructing notice that the user has to click away (like cookie warnings) adds a small level of inconvenience for the user, but allows you to convey information. Unless you can tell the user something useful - like at least an approximate launch date of the mobile version - I wouldn't even consider this approach. You can combine this approach with the next two.
- You can pick any space of the website which could be used for an ad (i.e. a place where the information doesn't bother the user too much and still gets noticed) and put the information there ("mobile version coming soon, register now to get notified"). The disadvantage is that you could use the same space for an actual ad and get paid, unless you're not running ads on your site. You can combine this approach with the next one.
- You can use a "mobile" link. Scroll down on this site, it's next to "contact us". The link lead the users to a page that informs them a mobile version is currently being worked on, and gives them an opportunity to sign up to be notified when the site is available. If the mobile version will only support certain devices (iOS/Android), state it clearly. You can also assure them the full site/desktop site is supposed to be fully functional on touchscreen devices and let them know where to report bugs.
- Do nothing.

Comment: Your logic will still work, but you have assumed it's a website the user is working on (The OP never concretely said that). It could be an app like UWP that can work on Windows PC and mobile devices. Might want to remove references to web specific logic

Comment: Thank you Peter for taking the time and replying, I definitely will take your feedback into consideration!

Comment: @draken removed references to "mobile site", good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Put up a notice:

"You are using the desktop version of this software.  We are developing a version optimised for mobile use, but it is not scheduled to become available until [scheduled rollout, or sampling date].

Do not show this notice [ ] until the mobile version is ready [ ] ever again"